# App already set as profile owner, but can't remove it anymore

Tags: android, admin, profile, device-owner, profile-owner

I have a class AdminReceiver extending DeviceAdminReceiver in my app.
Previously I made it profile owner via ADB shell

```
adb shell dpm set-active-admin com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.AdminReceiver 
adb shell dpm set-profile-owner com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.AdminReceiver
```

And everything went fine.
Subsequently, I wanted to remove it executing the following instruction from within my app programmatically:

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    try {
        dpm.clearProfileOwnerApp(packageName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "removingProfile: ", e);
    }
```

And I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Admin ComponentInfo{com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.AdminReceiver} does not own the profile
```

.

When I try to set again the profile owner via ADB I get the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set the profile owner, but profile owner is already set
```

.

It's crazy because when i try to remove the profile owner it's like it doesn't have it and if i try to make it profile owner it's like it already has!

Is there any solution without any factory reset of the device?

Comment: adb shell dpm remove-active-admin package.name/MyDeviceAdminReceiver  try this  cmd  and this method dpm.clearDeviceOwnerApp(context.getPackageName());

Comment: I receive "java.lang.SecurityException: Attempt to remove non-test admin ComponentInfo{com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.AdminReceiver}" if I try remove-active-admin from shell, with the "testOnly" flag to true set in the AndroidManifest.xml. If i run "clearDeviceOwner"  from within the app it says that it's not device owner.

Comment: try dpm.clearDeviceOwnerApp(this.getPackageName());

Comment: From the docs the profile owner should be the app if you don't specify the user in the shell. But something must have went wrong... For anyone else: just factory reset the device. (Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#dpm )

Answer (score 6):

Was facing the same issue, finally found a solution.

**Install Script**

```sh
adb install app.apk
adb shell dpm set-device-owner [your.package]/.DeviceAdminReceiver
```

**Uninstall Script**

```sh
adb install -r -t app-testOnly.apk
adb shell dpm remove-active-admin [your.package]/.DeviceAdminReceiver
adb shell pm uninstall [your.package]
```

**Note:** You need to create a [**testOnly**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#testOnly) version of the app first. Also if the actual app was signed, the testOnly has to be signed with the same certificate.

Comment: I can't create testOnly version because I can't reisntall app< I have message "app is already running"

Comment: Hi, I can successfully run remove-active-admin even without testOnly flag. How is that possible?